# How can I add a form in the thank you page in which the user won't have to resubmit the email address

Tags: orders, forms

I want to add a form in the thank you page (the page that's displayed after the order has been placed which contains the order details), however, I don't the user to resubmit the personal details as it has already been input during the order process. The only fields the user would need to write on were the message itself.

At the moment I've created the form (which required name, email, etc) and added to the thank you page through a template. I'm thinking about capturing the user details with jQuery and resubmit a custom form via ajax, however, I'd prefer to do it natively via PHP. Any suggestions on how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get any customer data in your template from the order object:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getLastOrderId());
$order->getCustomerEmail();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Success.phtml

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$order->getCustomerEmail();
```